# Some videos being replaced with duplicate entries when using YouTube.PlaylistItems.list

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube API with Google sheets to pull a list of all my videos by using `YouTube.PlaylistItems.list` with the `playlistId` parameter set to that of my uploads page, and I have a loop to go through page by page and print selected aspects of each item in a sheet.

The problem is that along the way (starting at around the 250th video), it returns ids that had already been returned and seems to think they are present at multiple different positions in the playlist, which they are not (this is not possible with the uploads list).

[image: Example of duplicate entries.]

This was working no problem before, so I'm guessing it's a bug, but I've put my code down below in case anyone can spot anything wrong with it. Any help would be much appreciated

```js
function retrieveInfo() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Imported')

  sheet.getRange('A2:H').clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var nextPageToken = '';
  var page = 0

  while (nextPageToken != null) {

    var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet,status', {
      playlistId: 'UU2yLF7zgs3Uz1c_eK75g2Sw',
      maxResults: 50,
      pageToken: nextPageToken
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {

      var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];

      sheet.getRange((page * 50) + (j + 2), 1).setValue(playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
      sheet.getRange((page * 50) + (j + 2), 2).setValue(playlistItem.snippet.title);
      sheet.getRange((page * 50) + (j + 2), 3).setValue(playlistItem.snippet.description);
      sheet.getRange((page * 50) + (j + 2), 4).setValue(playlistItem.status.privacyStatus);
      sheet.getRange((page * 50) + (j + 2), 12).setValue(playlistItem.snippet.position);
    }

    nextPageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken;
    var page = page + 1

  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // Stage 2

  var nextPageToken2 = ''
  var page2 = 0

  while (nextPageToken2 != null) {

    var bpoint = sheet.getRange((page2 * 50) + 2, 1).getValue()

    if (bpoint == "") {
      break
    }

    var ids = sheet.getRange(2 + (50 * page2), 1, 50, 1).getValues().toString();

    var videos = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet,contentDetails,fileDetails', {
      id: ids,
      maxResults: 50,
      pageToken: nextPageToken2
    });

    for (var k = 0; k < videos.items.length; k++) {

      var videoitem = videos.items[k]

      var durationinfo = videoitem.contentDetails.duration
      var langinfo = videoitem.snippet.defaultAudioLanguage
      var filename = videoitem.fileDetails.fileName

      sheet.getRange((page2 * 50) + (k + 2), 5).setValue(durationinfo)
      sheet.getRange((page2 * 50) + (k + 2), 7).setValue(langinfo)
      sheet.getRange((page2 * 50) + (k + 2), 8).setValue(filename)

    }

    nextPageToken = videos.nextPageToken;
    var page2 = page2 + 1

  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please obey to SO guidelines: don't post program output as image, but as (eventually [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text.

Comment: Unfortunately, invoking `PlaylistItems.list` on the uploads playlist ID `UU2yLF7zgs3Uz1c_eK75g2Sw` produced 317 **unique** video IDs (no duplicates). Therefore, the issue is not with the YouTube Data API, but is with your code.

Comment: Jay, not sure if it helps, but, looks odd that you have inside your `for` loop the `var page1` and `var page2` variables; change it as (*inside the loop*) = `page1++;` and `page2++;`. Also, for confirm it *is* a bug, save the results of `playlistResponse.items` and `videos.items` in plan JSON/separate variable in order to debug if the response does indeed returns duplicated values. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I tried replacing the `var page = page+1` for `page++` but the results were the exact same.

@stvar I have a large number of unlisted videos which I don't think will appear for anyone who is not an editor of the channel, so this is why you're not returning as many results as I am with the same code.

Comment: @JayAdama if your code is not the problem and you consider it's something wrong with the API's response. Consider post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B) - this behavior might be a bug I'm not aware of.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am just debugging a problem (totally different code) and see the same behavior where I see repeating results while other videos go missing (and actually I get about 5000 results where there should only be 1600 in the playlist). And to make the things more interesting: The problem seems to have appeared roughly at the time where you posted your question.